# jQuery Mobile ajax links not working properly in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a master layout looking somehow like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>

<body>
    <section data-role="page" data-theme="d">
        <section data-role="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    ...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.mobile")
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have a couple of controllers and templates pushing some code into content section of master layout.

When i click on a link:

```
<a href="/Orders/EditOrder/14960">Some order</a>
```

the ajax loader is shown, the url changes, but all I see is the broken markup of the original page. If I inspect the code I will see that there are two page sections in the DOM (which means that the target page is successfully injected but isn't shown). 
If I refresh page I will see the target page.

So what's wrong? Why can't I get the fancy JQM page transitions? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the data-ajax='false' on the links who were responsible for redirect you to another page.

JQuery Mobile uses AJAX navigation unless you tell it otherwise. The ASP.NET redirects have no problem to normal requests, but cause issues with AJAX. So my answer in this case is to turn off AJAX. For that, all you have to do is add the attribute data-ajax='false' to the tag.

In my case, an easy solution could be (as changing each Html.ActionLink/Url.Action is time consuming), adding this at the end of the _Layout.cshtml (just before closing of the 'body' tag).

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr("data-ajax", "false");
 });
```

});

That would be fine assuming you don't want jQuery mobile to use any Ajax with links too.
You can go ahead and use Ajax in most circumstances and only turn it off selectively where it can cause a problem.